# Magento - add product to cart with fixed quantity

Tags: magento

I'm adding a product programmatically in an action to the cart. 
Is it possible to set a fixed quantity in this step, which the user can't change afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set a fixed quantity that can't be manipulated by the user in some way or another, however you can mask it from the users view.

There are two ways to achieve this, first option is the non coding way around it but won't be as user friendly as the second:

**First option:**

Goto products backend -> Inventory and set 'Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart' to the fixed quantity. You can use the above answer to set the fixed quantity.

**Second option:**

If not, then you can modify the default.phtml (cart item render) to prevent the quantity adjustment field being rendered. You could use anything here to define the product, you could attach some custom options to identify the product.

Your looking for the line with the following:

```
<input name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty() ?>" size="4" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" />
```

Wrap it in an if else statement to differentiate the product you are adding programatically (you could use for example, Sku, product ID or a custom option). Instead of rendering the input field, just render a static 1 instead with no option to modify the quantity.

You could also add an option to the quote item and then pull via getOptionByCode() for the differentiation.

Doing both options would be a complete solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
 public function addAction()
{
    if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        $this->_goBack();
        return;
    }
    $cart   = $this->_getCart();
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    try {
        if (isset($params['qty'])) {
            $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
            );
            $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
        }
```

As you can see, in your CartController  you have add action.
The code above shows that this controller expects a param called "qty", that you can use.

I'm using magento1.8